# BackupAgent.onRestore not called when re-install app BUT called for bmgr restore command

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service, backup-agent

I am testing my custom BackupAgent. The below is my test in Simulator & Eclipse ADT

**Test 1 backup & restore using command ---- WORK WELL**

1. adb shell bmgr enabled
2. adb shell bmgr backup app_package
3. adb shell bmgr run ---------------------- Run backup (BackupAgent.onBackup called)
4. On the app, I deleted some data
5. adb shell bmgr restore app_package ------- Restore data from backup
6. All is restored including some data I deleted on step 4 ------ WORK WELL

**Test 2 Backup / uninstall app / re-install app ---- NOT WORK**

1. adb shell bmgr enabled
2. adb shell bmgr backup app_package
3. adb shell bmgr run ----------------------Run backup (BackupAgent.onBackup called)
4. adb uninstall app_package --------------- Uninstall the app after backup
5. Debug As / Android Application again ---- Application re-installed BUT NO data is restored ( data backup at step 3)

**Updated**

- I found Test 2 worked on Nexus 5 Simulator (API 19 - 4.4.2)
- BUT Test 2 didn't work on Nexus 4 Simulator (API 16-4.1.2)

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

very late, but have you tried setting the transport service to local?

> adb shell bmgr list transports

prints

```
android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
* com.google.android.gms/.backup.BackupTransportService
```

change it to the local one

> adb shell bmgr transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport

Comment: LocalTransport won't work across devices because it won't store the data in the google drive.